# How do I create a batch file that tells me the amount of memory I'm using?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I would like to create a batch file that gives me the memory of a needed file. For example, Chrome.exe. And send me an e-mail if the required memory is more than 1GB.

The application to be checked is on the terminal server and requires more and more memory. It should go to an e-mail to me, which tells me if the application requires more than 1GB of memory.

As info, the batch file will run on a terminal server. And is started by the task planning every 10 minutes.

**I have tried so far.**

```
 powershell.exe -command send-mailmessage -to test@example.de -cc test.e@example.de 
-from test@example.de -subject '"Batch-Testmail"' 
-smtpserver smtp.testserver.de -body '"Testmail"'
```

That is just a sample.

**And to check how much Workspace my programm needs. Chrome for example**

```
dir C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also think a PowerShell solution is better. WMI is nice, we could also do it with `Get-Process` and `Group-Object`, e.g.

```
$mem = get-process | Group-Object -Property Chrome.exe | 
    Format-Table @{n='Mem';e={'{0:N0}' -f (($_.Group|Measure-Object WorkingSet -Sum).Sum / 1MB)};a='right'}  -HideTableHeaders -AutoSize | Out-String

if($mem.Trim()/1 -gt 1024) {
    $EmailFrom = "noreply@do.too"
    $EmailTo = "you@do.too" 
    $Subject = "Memory Warning: $($mem.Trim()) MB accumulated" 
    $Body = "this is a notification from server x" 
    $SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
    $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
    $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
    $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $credentials); 
    $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks. I changed it a bit and incorporated it into my question as a solution.

Comment: @Philipp Your derived solution is pretty much the same. This is not how this site works.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking for the amount of memory used by a running process, you could start experiencing on this by using the following command:

```
wmic process where name='chrome.exe' get WorkingSetSize
```

It will dump to the screen the amount of memory used by each of the Chrome tabs you have opened.

Hope it helps. :)

I took the sample from here:

https://superuser.com/questions/1128692/extract-used-ram-of-program-by-batch

Using, then, the details you provided about the email, you could do something like this:

```
$app_loaded=wmic process where "workingsetsize>=1000000000" get name 
$EmailFrom = “yourgmailadress@gmail.com”
$EmailTo = “destination@somedomain.com”
$Subject = “The subject of your email”
$Body = “The application”.$app_loaded." is using more memory than expected."
$SMTPServer = “smtp.gmail.com”
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential(“usr”, “pass”);
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
```

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set CHROME_MEM=0
for /F "tokens=5" %%a in ('tasklist ^| find "chrome"') do (set MEM=%%a
 set /A CHROME_MEM=!CHROME_MEM! + !MEM:,=!
)
echo Total Memory is %CHROME_MEM% K
```

Comment: The usage of `%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq chrome.exe" /NH` would make the usage of `find` unnecessary. `set /A CHROME_MEM=!CHROME_MEM! + !MEM:,=!` could be written more efficient as `set /A CHROME_MEM+=!MEM:,=!` whereby best would be to use `set /A CHROME_MEM+=MEM` and insert above this line two more lines with `set "MEM=!MEM:,=!"` and `set "MEM=!MEM:.=!"`. On German Windows `.` is the comma instead of `,`.

Answer (score 0):

**The Solution is:**

```
$mem = get-process | Group-Object -Property chrome.exe | 
Format-Table @{n='Mem';e={'{0:N0}' -f (($_.Group|Measure-Object WorkingSet -Sum).Sum / 1MB)};a='right'}  -HideTableHeaders -AutoSize | Out-String

if($mem.Trim()/1 -gt 1024) {
   command send-mailmessage -to example@mail.com -cc examplecc@mail.com -from noreply@mail.com -subject '"Memory Warning: 1 GB accumulated"' -smtpserver smtp.server.com -body '"this is a notification from server x"' -priority High
}
```

Comment: Lots of errors. the `command` is wrong, we are already in a PowerShell script. `1GB` is still 1024 MB. https://blog.codinghorror.com/gigabyte-decimal-vs-binary/ & https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/kb-1024-vs-1000/
Otherwise no improvement to the already existing solutions.